# How to properly use a Subclassed silverlight control?

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, silverlight-4.0

I created this class where I wanted to override this specific event for the content control.

```
public class MyContentControl : ContentControl
{
    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //do something 
        //..........
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

However when I am using this control in my XAML everything compiles and works fine, but I am getting a runtime exception and I am not sure exactly why? Could someone point me in the right directions....

The exception I get is

> XamlParseException

UPDATED (Shows where abouts of the exceptions)

In the XAML I have:

```
xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:SilverlightProject.CustomControls"
```

and I use it like:

```
<ctrls:MyContentControl Grid.Column="0" x:Name="_contentControl" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the relevant Xaml that cause the exception. So far I see nothing that would result in this exception

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I updated my question. The exception happens at InitializeComponent() it gives my the line number of the xaml where I am placing/initializing the "MyContentControl"

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, copying your code verbatim does not result in an error.  Is this a templated control?  Do you have a default style for the MyContentControl?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: You are right, now that I tried this I can't reproduce any errors either with this example posted..... I will have to refine my question. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

Content controls require a default template to be created somewhere (e.g. in generic.xaml). They do not have a matching XAML file like user controls.

If you can provide more information, I can show you how to create an appropriate template.

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve/purpose of the control. The more you provide with code/XAML the easier it is to understand and provide a solution/example.

Comment: If you do not wish to publish too much here you can always contact us though our website. Happy to provide examples/advice (away 'til Sunday though).

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this. 
To start with. Give the fully qualified namespace.

Instead of

```
xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:SilverlightProject.CustomControls"
```

Use

```
xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:SilverlightProject.CustomControls;assembly=YourAssebmlyName"
```

If that, doesn't help.
You directly attach your control with the application. Then, enable Debug -> Exceptions. Check `Thrown` option for the CLR execetion checkbox. You have fair amount of possibility to get to know the cause.

Comment: BY adding the `assembly` I am getting an exception "Assembly....has been tampered with!"

Comment: Do you use key file for signing the assembly?

Comment: Sorry, no clue :( Let me observe this post as well.